# Ubuntu doesnt use the FGRLX graphics driver?

Tags: 12.04, ati, fglrx

I have got the Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit LTS Version and I want to play games with Steam. I tried out TF2 and it runs and has decent (not good) performance. I believe that my drivers are still running on the standard driver and not the AMD proprietary one.
I installed AMD drivers with gui and restarted the pc, but after that it just said the graphic driver is activated but not in use. If I type AMD in dash, I can access the control center and can change brightness with it.
In *System Option -> About* , it says that I'm using `Graphics: VESA: 01`, but I'm actually using a `HD 7870`.
How can I find out what graphic card I'm actually using or how can I install this one correctly?

Comment: how is it not in use? Did you install through "Additional drivers" or from AMD site? Do you mean that in System Settings > Details it says "Driver: unknown"?

Comment: You have your GUI working good? You can see the desktop but you have graphical issues?

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure first to install "Additional Drivers", usually you find it in the menu, or it can show in your panel as an update warning.

If you are a bit more brave you can also try to install the propietary driver from the AMD site.

Once you are sure the correct driver is intalled and running properly, it can fix your performance problems.

Give a try to the instructions here:

[AMD Catalyst Ubuntu Precise Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide)

After installing it you can test it with the commands

```
~$ fglrxinfo

~$ fgl_glxgears
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i tried it out with my current options, the console says: "simon@simon-pc:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11978 Compatibility Profile Context

simon@simon-pc:~$ fgl_glxgears
Using GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
" the gears where displayed correctly and very fast, why is display0 and screen 0 or is this nothing to be worried about

Comment: @FroZenViper It's nothing, short and simple: It's how Linux designates devices if you were to have another card it would be device1 or attach another display, display 1.