# RADEON! Driver activated but not in use [Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, x64]

Tags: drivers, radeon, catalyst

```
RADEON! Driver activated but not in use [Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, x64]
```

Sysinfo: VESA: WRESTLER

notebook: AMD  MSI CR650, AMD E-450, HD6320, 4Gb RAM

Comment: Have you rebooted the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check my answer to the following thread, maybe it can help you

[Ubuntu doesnt use the FGRLX graphics driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257569/ubuntu-doesnt-use-the-fgrlx-graphics-driver)

I recommend you to install the AMD propietary driver.